# Page number on blank pages?

Tags: page-numbering

For a document, I use the following setup:

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}

\renewcommand{\headfont}{\sffamily}

\clearscrheadfoot
\cfoot{\pagemark}

\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\defpagestyle{std}{(0 pt, 0 pt){\headmark\hfill}{\hfill\headmark}{}(\textwidth,1 pt)}{(0 pt, 0 pt){\pagemark}{\hfill\pagemark}{}(0 pt, 0 pt)}
```

Basically, this works just fine for me. However, I have a small but very nettlesome problem that all blank pages (after the TOC), produced by the command `openright` for example, do not contain a page number. I was wondering if there is a simple way to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: more often the complaint has been that blank pages contain an unwanted page number.  i'm not familiar with the koma packages, but in others, the page number on blank pages is managed (i.e. suppressed or not) by the `\cleardoublepage` command.  you might look for that definition, and adjust as appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

**KOMA-Script class**

I guess you are using a twosided KOMA-Script class. If that is true do not load the package `scrextend`. Instead use one the class option `cleardoublepage=<page style>`.

Example:

```
\documentclass[
  cleardoublepage=plain
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummytext

\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument\Blindtext
\blinddocument\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Other class**

But if you are using a different class you can load `scrextend` with the option `cleardoublepage=<page style>`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[
  cleardoublepage=plain
]{scrextend}

\usepackage[automark,headsepline=1pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummytext

%\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument\Blindtext
\blinddocument\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: For other classes one can load `\usepackage{emptypage}` (it's compatible with `fancyhdr`, for instance).

Comment: @egreg The OP is not asking for empty pages. There should be a page number on the blank pages. Additionally `scrextend` is also compatible with `fancyhdr`.