# Abstract and Acknowledgements in book class

Tags: page-numbering, abstract, acknowledgements

I know this is a much asked question, but I could not find a proper answer anyway. I want to include an abstract and acknowledgements to my thesis, and I succeeded up to some extent with the help of this [topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68222/define-abstract-environment-in-book). Let me start with a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}  %%% here
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \titlepage
      \null\vfil
      \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
      \begin{center}%
        \bfseries \abstractname
        \@endparpenalty\@M
      \end{center}}%
     {\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
  This is my abstract
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 Thanks Mum!
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter 
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
% etc.

\end{document}
```

**My problem:** My problem is two-fold. First of all, there is no page number on both the abstract- and acknowledgements page. Secondly, it resets the page numbering on the acknowledgement page. So how could I get the page numbering correct and present on all pages?

Comment: Why not letting the abstract and the acknowledgments simply be unnumbered chapters? You'd get a uniform style, wouldn't you?

Comment: I don't want a uniform style for the abstract and the acknowledgements, that's the thing. I think it looks more professional if you choose another, very plain, style for the abstract and acknowledgements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'problem' is the definition of `\titlepage` in `book.cls`, having

```
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
```

The first command will apply the 'empty' pagestyle whereas the second one resets the page counter (`\@ne` is LaTeX core command for being '1' -- think of `\@ne` = `\one` ;-))

This can be removed by redefinition of `\titlepage` or by a patch. The patch is shorter here.

Be careful if the `twoside` option is used -- in this case the patch won't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}  %%% here
\makeatletter
\if@titlepage
\xpatchcmd{\titlepage}{%
  \thispagestyle{empty}%
  \setcounter{page}\@ne
  }{%
%Do nothing here
}{\typeout{Successfully patched!}}{\typeout{Patching failed!}}
\newenvironment{abstract}{%
  \titlepage
  \null\vfil
  \@beginparpenalty\@lowpenalty
  \begin{center}%
    \bfseries \abstractname
    \@endparpenalty\@M
  \end{center}}%
{\par\vfil\null\endtitlepage}
\else
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
    \if@twocolumn
    \section*{\abstractname}%
    \else
    \small
    \begin{center}%
      {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
    \end{center}%
    \quotation
    \fi}
  {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\begin{abstract}
  This is my abstract
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 Thanks Mum!
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter 
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
% etc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Christian,

Thanks for your help (again btw!). I will eventually accept your answer, because it works great. Still some issues though: The package `\usepackage{xpatch}` seems to put a numbering (in arabic) on my titlepage and the page after that. Can I get rid of it?

Another issue, but I may have to look into that myself first. In my complete thesis document, it does not seem to work as well either. It does give a numbering on  the abstract and acknowledgements pages, but not on the pages after them strangely enough? Any educated guesses on that perhaps?

Comment: I thought `titlepage` should be numbered too? For the real document: Do you have some other `\pagestyle{...}` commands?

Comment: Sorry for waiting so long to respond. First of all, let me apologize, I wanted the page numbering on all pages, except the title page (and the one page after that of course). After that, I need roman numbering for the `\frontmatter`. Now, I did some trouble shouting to reproduce my problem with a MWE and you can reproduce it by simply adding `\usepackage{scrextend}` to your MWE above. Maybe it's a bug? I really can not do without this package btw. If this is an unfortunate bug or something, then I will settle with a less elegant solution with `\paragraph{}` structures.

Comment: @Koen: `scrextend` is KOMA stuff :-(

Comment: @ Christian: Hmm, well I will not use it for any other project in the future then, but for now I'm stuck with it. Thanks for your help and since it otherwise works as it should I will accept your answer!

Comment: In case somebody reads this in the future, I was able to fixe the problem with the `scrextend` package by calling it as `\usepackage[cleardoublepage=plain]{scrextend}`. I found the solution from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244689/page-number-on-blank-pages)